# The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]

Tags: c#, .net, assemblyinfo

I want to append our application version with the build number.  For example, `1.3.0.201606071`.

When setting this in the AssemblyInfo, I get the following compilation error:

> Error CS7034  The specified version string does not conform to the
>   required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]

Assembly info:

```
[assembly:System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.0.201606071")]
[assembly:System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.201606071")]
[assembly:System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("1.0.0.201606071")]
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Note: `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` does not have restrictions as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: We ran into this same problem, and just ended up formatting our date like a version (ex. `2017.12.20.1234`, where 1234 is our build number)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The maximum value for either of the parts is 65534, as you read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2007/01/03/why-are-build-numbers-limited-to-65535/). This is a limit imposed by the operating system, so not even specific to .NET. Windows puts the version numbers into two integers, which together form four unsigned shorts.

[Adding some metadata to it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) (for the `*` option I guess) makes the maximum allowed value `UInt16.MaxValue - 1 = 65534` (Thanks to [Gary Walker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2704619/gary-walker) for noticing):

> All components of the version must be integers greater than or equal to 0. Metadata restricts the major, minor, build, and revision components for an assembly to a maximum value of `UInt16.MaxValue - 1`. If a component exceeds this value, a compilation error occurs.

Your `201606071` exceeds this limit.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue when trying to set a star value (`1.0.*`) in a .NET Core project with the new _csproj_ format file, having set `GenerateAssemblyInfo` to `false`. Any ideas? I'm looking to achieve auto increment in .NET Core / Standard projects of the new _csproj_ format file.

Comment: No, I am sorry. Please ask a new question @Shimmy

Comment: @Shimmy Did you end up asking that question? What did you find out?

Comment: We need a "Best of both worlds" solution for Assembly DATE 
AND Assembly Semantic Versioning.  1.yyyy.mmdd.buidNum

Comment: I was getting this error in Visual Studio 2022 in a .NET Standard 2.0 library and managed to figure out what I was doing wrong after re-reading the documentation and wanted to share what I did wrong in case others have the same issue. I had entered `1.0.*.*` with two wildcard asterisks. The solution was to change it to only one asterisk `1.0.*`.

Answer (score 37):

If you are targeting `netcoreapp2.0` and don't have `AssemblyInfo.cs` at all you can fix

> **error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the required format**

by adding this into your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>False</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: For me the problem was that my `.csproj` file contained `<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>` but I was targetting .Net 4.0 as well. I removed this and the compiler worked once more. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: THIS is the real answer.

Comment: Had the described error when attempting to build a .NET 5 application in TFS 2015 with Visual Studio Build task. This is exactly what was missing. Thank you Dmitry

Comment: This was it for me in .NET 6 and TFS 2015 -> VS build task. Thank you Dmitry!

Answer (score 15):

[It's because each number in the version is a ushort](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2007/01/03/why-are-build-numbers-limited-to-65535/)! That's a pity.

Comment: Actually its 65534 not 65535.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Yes, a ushort is limited to 65535, but the [build number is limited to 65534](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)

Comment: Oddly, each field in AssemblyVersion is limited to 65534, but in AssemblyFileVersion the limit it 65535. Yeah for consistency!

Comment: One also has to wonder why there is `Version.MajorRevision` and `Version.MinorRevision` (the high and low 16 bits respectively) if the `Revision` field is only 16-bits total.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do it (both in .NET Framework and in .NET Core) for the AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion, just not for the AssemblyVersionAttribute.

- The `AssemblyVersionAttribute` is the only one that's actually limited to 4 `ushort` values - if you specify anything more the compiler will complain with `error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]`, and there is nothing you can do about it.
- The `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` can be used with larger values, e.g. to encode date values with (for example in the Patch part of a semver), but will generate `warning CS7035: The specified version string does not conform to the recommended format - major.minor.build.revision`. Luckily, because it's a warning, it can be suppressed (see below).
- The `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` isn't constrained to anything and can contain a prerelease semver like "`1.2.6-CI20220906`", or any other random string really.

That is, the following will work:

```
#pragma warning disable CS7035 // The specified version string does not conform to the recommended format - major.minor.build.revision 

[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.4.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.4.220831.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("1.4.220831-prerelease+build")]

#pragma warning restore CS7035
```

For .NET Core, you can either:

- [Disable auto-generated assembly attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138418/equivalent-to-assemblyinfo-in-dotnet-core-csproj) and include these attributes in your own AssemblyInfo.cs
- Keep the version in the csproj file. In that case, in "Project properties", under "Build", "Suppress specific warnings", include "7035" in the list of warnings to suppress.

Answer (score 5):

In the .csproj file you must set Deterministic to false. Then accepts the compiler a '*' in the Build or Revision.

Answer (score 1):

This limitation only applies to the Assembly and File version so if you are using .Net Core 2.x you can get around this limitation by settings a separate version of each in the csproj.

```
</PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.1.1.9000001</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix>$(VersionSuffix)</VersionSuffix>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.1.1.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.1.1.0</FileVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases maybe [**Treat warnings as errors**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#treatwarningsaserrors) is enabled in project properties and versions like `1.3.0-4011` will cause following error:

> Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(35,32): error CS7035: The specified version string does not conform to the recommended format - major.minor.build.revision

So you can Change it using Visual Studio by selecting `None` or by setting `TreatWarningsAsErrors` to `false` in `.csproj` file.

[image: Treat warnings as errors in project properties]

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\..\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i needed to move the Dockerfile file to SOlution Items folder which was defined on the base folder of the solution